# This code doesn't print anything

Tags: javascript, oop, object

can you explain to me why this code shows error and doesn't print anything?

```
var myObject = {
  test: "bar",
  myfunc: function() {
    var self = this;
    console.log("outer myfunc: this.test = " + this.test);
    console.log("outer myfunc: self.test = " + self.test);
    (function () { 
      console.log("inner myfunc: this.test = " + this.test);
      console.log("outer myfunc: self.test = " + self.test);
    } ());
  }
};
```

It compiles successfully with no errors, but after running it print only undefined string

Comment: Can you show your function call code?

Comment: What do you mean compile? JS is interpreted!

Comment: Where/how are you calling your function? This code on it's own doesn't do anything.

Comment: @PattonPierce [That's not completely true.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/138541/39096)

Comment: if you call `myObject.myfunc()` you will get `bar` as the output for all but one  `inner myfunc: this.test = undefined` is that the undefined that you are referring to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating your function that can be invoked in the future.  But you are not actually calling it.  You need to call it.

```
//Here's where you create your function
var myObject = {
  test: "bar",
  myfunc: function() {
    var self = this;
    console.log("outer myfunc: this.test = " + this.test);
    console.log("outer myfunc: self.test = " + self.test);
    (function () { 
      console.log("inner myfunc: this.test = " + this.test);
      console.log("outer myfunc: self.test = " + self.test);
    } ());
  }
};

//Now that you've created your function, you can use it.
myObject.myFunc();
```

Section "Invoking a JavaScript Function" in this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

On line 3 you have defined a method `myFunc` on your object `myObject`. This will only `console.log` when you invoke `myObject.myfunc();`

On line 7 you create an IIFE. This defines a function and immediately invokes it. This will also only console.log when you invoke `myObject.myfunc();`

myFunc does not exist globally. It is a method attached to myObject.

`console.log("outer myfunc: this.test = " + this.test);`

`console.log("outer myfunc: self.test = " + self.test);`

Here on lines 5 and 6 `self` and `this` will always refer to the same object. If you call invoke the function `myObject.myfunc();` then `this.test` and `self.test` will both evaluate to `"bar"`.

Now, if you do `setTimeout(myObject.myfunc, 0);` then both `self` and `this` will refer to the `window` object so `test` will be undefined (`window.test` is currently undefined). This is because the `this` object is determined dynamically at runtime in Javascript. Registering `myObject.myfunc` as a callback will evaluate to a pointer to the defined function. Invoking your myfunc in this context will be a free function invocation -- without `myObject` as the `this` context it will default to the `window` object.

`console.log("inner myfunc: this.test = " + this.test);`

`console.log("outer myfunc: self.test = " + self.test);`

On lines 8 and 9 `this` will always refer to the `window` object and print `undefined` unless you assign `test` to the window. `Self` will follow the pattern explained above.

Answer (score -1):

Your code will not print anything unless you use `myfunc`, which can be done by accessing `myFunc` from `myObject`, just like accessing an object property. So along with your existing code, write anywhere after the following:

```
myObject.myfunc();
```

Which should display the console output you're expecting. If you see any errors beyond that, please let me know by adding to the comments below.

Comment: thanks man, the output is outer myfunc: this.test = bar
outer myfunc: self.test = bar
inner myfunc: this.test = undefined
outer myfunc: self.test = bar